# How to not load zeros from a txt file with numpy.loadtxt?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a huge amount of .txt files that consist of one-column numeric values, such as:

```
-0.42424
0.5466
0.9
-0.4577
0
1.32
-0.933
...
```

Using the code

```
import numpy as np
My_data = np.loadtxt("/pathtodata")
```

loads `My_data` into Python. Is there any possibilty to tell `np.loadtxt` that it should *not* load zero values (0) or at least replace them by another value of choice? Of course, one could remove or replace zeros in all txt files by hand. But the number of txt files and the list of values they contain is massive. Therefore, I am looking for an option to do this in Python, possibly without changing the actual data files.

I don't want to remove values/rows that start with 0, but rows that only contain `0`, such as row 5 in my example above.

Comment: what about using `np.loadtxt("/pathtodata", comments='0\n')` (in case there are no comments in the file). also, if last line has a 0, it will be added to the matrix

Comment: This is a very nice idea and it works, thank you!

Comment: @jsofri beware that your solution will damage integers ending with `0`, for example if file will be holding number: `5` then `100` then `7` your solution will result in array holding `5` then `10` then `7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
-0.42424
0.5466
0.9
-0.4577
0
1.32
-0.933
```

then

```
import numpy as np
def getnonzeros(filename):
    with open(filename,"rb") as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.strip() == b"0":
                continue
            yield line

arr = np.loadtxt(getnonzeros("file.txt"))
print(arr)
```

output

```
[-0.42424  0.5466   0.9     -0.4577   1.32    -0.933  ]
```

Explanation: `np.loadtxt` can accept `bytes` `yield`ing generator so I craft suitable one. It does iterate over lines (so there is no loading of whole file into memory) of file open in `r`ead-`b`inary mode, skipping lines which are equal to `b"0"` after jettisoning leading and trailing whitespaces. **Disclaimer**: this code assume zeros in your file are always rendered as `0` not for example `0.0000`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed code and explanation. I just read your additional comment that you added above on possible damages to the dataset when using "\n" for comment in numpy.loadtxt. I will consequently use your code.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an elegant solution to me. However, it removes the 0s after the data has been imported, not while it's being imported. (Not sure if that matters.)

```py
import numpy as np

my_data = np.loadtxt("pathtodata")
my_data = my_data[~(my_data==0)]
```

Comment: A very elegant solution indeed. It works fine, thanks!

Comment: I think it's better to use `my_data!=0` but good solution